# jQuery do something depends of url path

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add css class to all url's, that begining from example.com/mine/first. I know how add classes from root address, but I can't do this for /mine/first path.

This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var pathnameArr = location.pathname.split('/');
    switch (pathnameArr[1]) {
 case 'mine/first':
  $(".container").addClass('dontshow');
 break;
 case 'mine/second':
  $(".container").addClass('dontshow');
 break;
 }
});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If "/" is your delimiter, 'mine/first' will never be a value.

Comment: if you `split('/')`, would you get `mine` in `pathnameArr[1]` and `first` in `pathnameArr[2]`?

Comment: Did you debug this and see what `console.log(pathnameArr[1])` is?

Comment: I can say that I just don't know jQuery at all :(

Comment: @sloan, what is the value of your `location.pathname`? Output from `alert(location.pathname);`?

Comment: /mine/first for first uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust way to test this might be to use [RegExp.prototype.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
$(function() {
  if ((/^\/mine\/(first|second?)/).test(window.location.pathname)) {
    $('.container').addClass('dontshow');
  }
});
```

Comment: You can also expand this to any path after `/mine/` pretty easily by changing the regex to `/^\/mine\/(.+?)`, which will match `/mine/first`, `/mine/second`, `/mine/whatever`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Travis, but in Chromium I have "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing / " Error only.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `indexOf` ?

```
(function(){
    var pathnameArr = location.pathname;
    if (pathnameArr.indexOf('mine/first')>-1) {
      $(".container").addClass('dontshow');
    }
    if (pathnameArr.indexOf('mine/second')>-1) {
      $(".container").addClass('dontshow');
    }
});
```

Comment: good solution, just be aware it won't work in old IE (<9) without a polyfill. It may not work in newer IE depending on the doctype you use.

Comment: Is not a problem for `array.indexOf` only? Here it is a string (just kept the variable name)

Comment: @davidkonrad is right `String.prototype.indexOf` has been implemented since the 1st edition of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

Since "/" is your delimiter "/" will not appear in any of your values in `pathnameArr`. Instead try switching on the last parameter:

```
$(function(){
    var pathnameArr = location.pathname.split('/');
    switch (pathnameArr.pop()) {
        case 'first':
            $(".container").addClass('dontshow');
            break;
        case 'second':
            $(".container").addClass('dontshow');
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression.

```
$(function () {
    var regexp = /^\/mine\/(first|second)/;
    if ( regexp.test(location.pathname) ) {
        $(".container").addClass('dontshow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /